# Java 8 Sorting with Comparator and Optionals

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to sort a list of object based on multiple fields(some of them fields within a reference object). The following code is made up just for illustration and sample purpose and is not actual code.
AuthorBookStat This is the object I am trying to sort (Removed Getters and setters to increase readability)

```
public class AuthorBookStat {
  private String name;
  private AuthorStats authorStats;

}
```

AuthorStats

```
public class AuthorStats {
  private String genre;
  private BookStats bookStats;
}
```

BookStats

```
public class BookStats {
  Double averageBookRatings;
  Integer pages;
  String primaryMarket;
}
```

Now I want to sort first based on primaryMarket, then ratings, then pages and finally genre

Here is what I have done and it works well

```
    public class AuthorTest {
      public static void  main(String args[]){
        AuthorBookStat authorBookStat = new AuthorBookStat();
        authorBookStat.setName("A");
    
        AuthorStats authorStats = new AuthorStats();
        authorStats.setGenre("fantasy");
    
        BookStats bookStats = new BookStats();
        bookStats.setAverageBookRatings(3.5d);
        bookStats.setPages(100);
        bookStats.setPrimaryMarket("US");
    
        authorStats.setBookStats(bookStats);
        authorBookStat.setAuthorStats(authorStats);
    
        AuthorBookStat authorBookStat1 = new AuthorBookStat();
        authorBookStat1.setName("A");
    
        AuthorStats authorStats1 = new AuthorStats();
        authorStats1.setGenre("sci-fi");
    
        BookStats bookStats1 = new BookStats();
        bookStats1.setAverageBookRatings(3.5d);
        bookStats1.setPages(100);
        bookStats1.setPrimaryMarket("DE");
    
        authorStats1.setBookStats(bookStats1);
        authorBookStat1.setAuthorStats(authorStats1);
    
        List<AuthorBookStat> authorBookStatList = new ArrayList<>();
        authorBookStatList.add(authorBookStat);
        authorBookStatList.add(authorBookStat1);
    
    
        Comparator<AuthorBookStat> sortByPrimaryMarket =
            Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getAuthorStats().getBookStats().getPrimaryMarket());
        Comparator<AuthorBookStat> sortByRatings =
            Comparator.comparingDouble(a -> a.getAuthorStats().getBookStats().getAverageBookRatings());
        Comparator<AuthorBookStat> sortByPages =
            Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.getAuthorStats().getBookStats().getPages());
        Comparator<AuthorBookStat> sortByGenre =
            Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getAuthorStats().getGenre());
    
        var sortedList = authorBookStatList
            .stream()
            .sorted(
                sortByPrimaryMarket.thenComparing(sortByRatings)
                    .thenComparing(sortByPages).thenComparing(sortByGenre)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    //    authorBookStatList.sort(sortByPrimaryMarket.thenComparing(sortByRatings)
    //        .thenComparing(sortByPages).thenComparing(sortByGenre));
// I can also sort based on the commented lines above. So both works
        System.out.println(sortedList);
      }
    }
```

This works fine and gives me the following output which is perfect

```
[AuthorBookStat{primaryMarket='DE', ratings=3.5, pages=100, genre=sci-fi},
 AuthorBookStat{primaryMarket='US', ratings=3.5, pages=100, genre=fantasy}]
```

Now, Let's say couple of fields are null and I have optional getters. For example in Bookstats ratings and primaryMarket

```
public Optional<Double> getAverageBookRatings() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(averageBookRatings);
  }
public Optional<String> getPrimaryMarket() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(primaryMarket);
  }
```

How would I sort then in the case where if there is null rest of the fields are considered first for one and for other not. For example in case primary Market is null then it gets last precedence

> ```
> [AuthorBookStat{primaryMarket='DE', ratings=3.5, pages=100, genre=sci-fi},
>  AuthorBookStat{ratings=3.5, pages=100, genre=fantasy}]
> ```

Comment: You could provide a variant of `Comparators.NullComparator` that compares optionals (maybe there is a version already as part of a library like Guava or Apache Commons) or map the optionals to their values of `null` and then use `Comparator.nullsFirst(...)` or `nullsLast(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Comparator.nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst(java.util.Comparator)) or [`Comparator.nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast(java.util.Comparator)), you can specify null-safe comparators to be used for comparing the keys, taking into consideration the `Optional` can return null by using `Optional.orElse(null)`:

```
Comparator<AuthorBookStat> sortByPrimaryMarket = Comparator
            .comparing(a -> a.getAuthorStats().getBookStats().getPrimaryMarket().orElse(null), Comparator
                    .nullsFirst(String::compareTo));
Comparator<AuthorBookStat> sortByRatings = Comparator
            .comparing(a -> a.getAuthorStats().getBookStats().getAverageBookRatings().orElse(null), Comparator
                    .nullsFirst(Double::compareTo));
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. One final question, is it also possible to have the same in case geBookStats() is also optional?

Comment: @SandeepNair Yes you can just treat that case by returning null in your key extractor lambda. The `Optional.map` method can be helpful in that case.